# Android's Activity == Windows' Modal Dialog Box?

Tags: android, windows, android-activity, modal-dialog

I have been programming for Windows for years and just now beginning to learn Android... Lots of new terminology so I naturally compare new terms (or notions) to ones I am familiar with.

In Android's "Application Fundamentals", the first of 4 application components is named an **activity** and is described as "a *visual* user interface for *one* focused endeavor the user can undertake... Moving from one activity to another is accomplished by having the *current activity start the next one*."

This sounds to me alot like the behavior of a Windows dialog box.

Is it?

What is your view on this?

Comment: `so I naturally compare new terms` Don't do that

Comment: Well don't. Not everything has an equivalent in "windows programming", whatever that means. You're going to implement things the way you would in windows instead of how they should be done in android. Learn new concepts. Saying you can't because you're too old isn't an excuse.

Comment: Comparing terms from a Windows desktop application to a mobile application isn't going to work. While "one focused endeavor" may be a modal dialog on the desktop, there isn't space for multiple "endeavors" on mobile, hence an Activity is the basic unit.

Comment: @Christopher Thanks and +1. Your comment is informative and useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `Activity` is closer to a window, or, better yet, a page in a Web app. A `Dialog` is closer to a dialog.

Comment: Can you explain *why* an activity is closer to a Window? Especially when the term "window" already exists in the Android world?

Comment: "Window" only exists in the Android world at a low, technical level. Activities are so-called because they represent a single, well-defined *activity* that the user is undertaking, e.g. writing an SMS, selecting a contact, viewing a web page.

Comment: @Christopher Thanks and +1 again for your explanation.

Comment: @Christopher based on your last comment, is it correct to say that an activity is **not** a visual entity (like views, windows or dialogs)?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. An activity **is** a visual entity but it is also an... activity (with 4 states: running, paused, stopped, shut down).